# NestJs, after builds production.env undefined

Tags: deployment, build, environment-variables, nestjs

NestJs, tried everything. I am trying to build my application.

```
"build": "nest build"`,
"start:prod": "node dist/main",
```

As a result

```
process.env.PORT undefined
process.env.POSTGRES_HOST undefined
[Nest] 22952  - 30.03.2022, 15:33:48     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 22952  - 30.03.2022, 15:33:48     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +126ms
[Nest] 22952  - 30.03.2022, 15:33:48     LOG [InstanceLoader] SequelizeModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 22952  - 30.03.2022, 15:33:48     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 22952  - 30.03.2022, 15:33:48     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 22952  - 30.03.2022, 15:33:48   ERROR [SequelizeModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)
```

I use `"cross-env": "^7.0.3"`

my app.module.ts :

```
imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
        }),
        SequelizeModule.forRoot({
            dialect: 'postgres',
            host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
            port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
            username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
            password: String(process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD),
            database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
..
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.. Locally everything works.

`"start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch"`

Comment: In the `start:prod` you didn't define those env. vars like you did in `start:dev`, then they will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dot (`.`) at the beginning of the `NODE_ENV.env` file. Do you also have `.production.env` file in the directory root of your application?

Comment: Yes, `.production.env`  file in the my directory